# How to signup with a personalized email using Google Oauth?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an application that authenticates users via Google Oauth. When I click Signup button, a signup screen would pop up as shown in the figure below.

[image]

The problem is that I want users to signup emails with domain name of my organization. Specifically, the username suffix should be `@my_organization.com` instead of `@gmail.com` as displayed in the figure. I have tried to modify the Oauth Consent Screen but there seems to be no option to configure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you mentioned the "Sign in with Google" is for login purposes through OAuth protocol when the accounts already exists in an organization, I am afraid this is not intended to delegate user creation since this is a task only domain administrators are allowed within an organization.

The most you can achieve from OAuth is to force the sign in with an specific domain; you can do this by modifying the "hd" parameter in the authentication request you are sending using the Google's OAuth 2.0 API. Here you can check on this topic: [click here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#hd-param)

As mentioned above, if you are looking to create user accounts with a specific domain you need to be an administrator in a Google Workspace account.

I hope this information helps!

Comment: If that's the case, can you provide me a tutorial where the Signup button can be removed (I would rather that the users cannot register since they can only register @gmail.com account)? I have searched everywhere but there seems to be no result about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use oAuth with registered Google accounts.
With Google Workspace you can use a domain in your Gmail, [see](https://workspace.google.com/intl/en/products/gmail/).
But if that's not possible and you want a quick way to authenticate, maybe [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) or similar tools can help.

Comment: I have updated my question, can you review it?